# Need to understand how javascript functions are called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is part of a code. The question is, does this line `"$("#b_facetNewChild").button().click(function(){"` means that the following should be fired when the button "facetNewChild" is clicked? Because there is no "onClick" function at the button. Also, can you explain briefly, what does it mean to have this nested into another function "newChildFacet()" and how to call it?
Sorry, but I am new to javascript.Thanks!

```
function newChildFacet()
    {
        //  button click
        $("#b_facetNewChild").button().click(function(){
                //get selected fId
            var $fId=getSfSelectedFIds();
            if($fId.length>0 && $fId.split(",").length!=1)
            {
                messageBox("Tip","Please select <b>ONE</b> as the parent facet. If no facet is selected, the new facet will be created under <b>root</b>.");
                return false;
            }

            //some more stuff here!
        });

        // newChildFacetDialog
        $("#newChildFacetDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "New Child Facet",
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "Create": function() {
                    //get data
                    var $parentId=getSfSelectedFIds();

                    });
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, yes it bound as a `click` event handler, so it'll run when `#b_facetNewChild` is clicked - you won't see this in source, it's stored elsewhere in the DOM.

You can call it by invoking the `click` event handlers on that element, like this:

```
$("#b_facetNewChild").click();
```

It doesn't matter that it's a nested/anonymous function, all we care about here is it's a `click` event handler on that element, so you can trigger it any of the following ways:

```
$("#b_facetNewChild").click();
$("#b_facetNewChild").trigger("click");
$("#b_facetNewChild").triggerHandler("click");
```

Comment: how do I do that? I want to call this function when I click the button. Is it set to that already?

Comment: @Ahmad - If you run `newChildFacet()` it'll hook the `click` handlers up, then yes it'll run on click, just make sure to call `newChildFacet()` at some point after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: If this was written in an external file .js other than the page file, does this differ in anyhow?
I'm afraid I'm not sure what is "DOM" exactly?

Comment: @Ahmad - jQuery has a `document.ready` handler to your code executes when the page is ready the DOM is the document object model, think of HTML as the definition of your objects, when they're parsed and loaded into a tree to render that's the DOM, so for example when we do `$("#b_facetNewChild")` it's searching the DOM actually running `document.getElementById("b_facetNewChild")`...you want to be sure the DOM's loaded so that the `id="b_facetNewChild"` element is there to find.  At the end of your external JS you can just put `$(newChildFacet)` for example, this is a `document.ready` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You got it right.

`$("#b_facetNewChild").button().click(function(){ ... })` does exactly what you mean. However, you won't see an `onclick` handler in the HTML, but rather only if you inspect the DOM/JS element itself (for example, by using FireBug).

The fact that this call is located inside a function simply means it will only be called (i.e. callback attached to the button) once the wrapping function is called.